# Drools Question about equality in memberOf and contains

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I would appreciate if someone would explain how memberOf and contains evaluates equality between objects.

```
  rule "Compare orders"
  when
    $u:   User( $order: order )
    Order( $order memberOf orderLines )  
  then
 //do stuff
  end
```

In this example I found , how does the engine determine the user's order is a memberOf the order lines?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `memberOf` operator is implemented by the following method: [ContainsOperator.eval()](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-model/drools-canonical-model/src/main/java/org/drools/model/operators/ContainsOperator.java#L28). This method uses [Collection.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) to do the check.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Is it based on object equality by comparing the fields?